# HTML5 Email validation pattern does not validate .edu.au, accepts even just edu.a

Tags: html, design-patterns

I'm supposed to be accepting only `usyd.edu.au` email addresses. The validation works, but it also works with `usyd.edu.a` emails. I want it to accept only when complete `.au` is entered. The pattern I have which works so far is:

```
input type="email", placeholder="Email" name="txtName" id="txtEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[usyd]+\.[edu]+\.[au]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Close but not right.

`[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[usyd]+\.[edu]+\.[au]`

- `[a-z0-9._%+-]+` simple enough Allow a-z or 0-9 or . or _ or % or + or -
- `@` only allow @
- `[usyd]+` allow one or more of u, s, y or d. Which could just be 'u'
- `\.` only allow .

But the suggestion from Austen is also wrong:

`[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(usyd)+\.(edu)+\.(au)`

- `(usyd)+` would allow you to enter `'usydusydusyd'`
- `(edu)+` would allow you to enter `'edueduedueduedu'`

There is no reason for the parenthesis. and you definitely do not want the `'+'` since that allows *one-or-more*.

Instead you want this:

`^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@usyd\.edu\.au$`

This will make sure that nothing odd exists at the beginning of the string (The '^') and that the string ends with `'@usyd.edu.au'` (The '$')

```css
input:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email", placeholder="Email" name="txtName" id="txtEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@usyd\.edu\.au"/>
```

Comment: Very well said. If I don't look at my code and cringe after 3 months then I have not learned enough.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it! If you change the square brackets [] in the last 3 places in your regex to be round brackets () then it will work as expected.
ex: `[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(usyd)+\.(edu)+\.(au)`

Here's why:

- `[au]` will match a SINGLE character found within the brackets. (Either an `a`, or `u`)
- `(au)` will match EVERYTHING found inside the brackets. (Exactly `au`)